# Citation right next to an inline equation

Tags: math-mode, citing, inline

I have a problem related to placing a citation right after an inline equation. If you look at the second line of text in the following image, the problem should become apparent.

[image: A problem with a citation and an inline formula, shown on the second line of this text.]

The claim is that continuously differentiable functions are dense in **L**<sup>1</sup> [–*π*, *π*], and a natural place for the citation comes right after the formula, before the period, which makes it look like the citation might be a part of the formula. In the image I have moved the citation after the period, which solves the problem of differentiating between the citation and the formula, but this solution might be grammatically incorrect.

Any recommendations as to how should I approach this problem?

Comment: Can you add a word before the reference, like, `, see` or `, cf.`, etc.?

Comment: This could work.